# Sending email using flask

Tags: python, email, flask

I am using flask to send emails to user who submits a form in a contact page.

I have tried to test it myself but even If i fill the whole form. Every time I hit submit, I get a validation error saying that I must fill in the form. In my log it says I get a 200, which means the post was a success.

Here is the code:

**routes.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash
from forms import ContactForm
from flask.ext.mail import Message, Mail


mail = Mail()

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = 'development key'

app.config["MAIL_SERVER"] = "smtp.gmail.com"
app.config["MAIL_PORT"] = 465
app.config["MAIL_USE_SSL"] = True
app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"] = 'contact@gmail.com'
app.config["MAIL_PASSWORD"] = '*********'

mail.init_app(app)


app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'development key'

@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
  form = ContactForm()

  if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.validate() == False:
      flash('All fields are required.')
      return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
    else:
      msg = Message(form.subject.data, sender="contact@gmail.com")
      msg.body = """
      From: %s <%s>
      %s
      """ % (form.name.data, form.email.data, form.message.data)
      mail.send(msg)

      return 'Form posted.'

  elif request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
```

**Forms.py**

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, SubmitField, validators, ValidationError

class ContactForm(Form):
  name = TextField("Name", [validators.Required("Please Enter Your Name")])
  email = TextField("Email",[validators.Required("Please enter your email address"), validators.email("Please enter your email address")])
  subject = TextField("Subject", [validators.Required("Please enter a subject.")])
  message = TextAreaField("Message", [validators.Required("Please enter a message.")])
  submit = SubmitField("Send")
```

Comment: Why is there JavaScript in your username and sender fields? Also, post the contents of your `forms` module.

Comment: @Blender This is my first time using flask and i am following a tutorial on sending [email on flask](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/intro-to-flask-adding-a-contact-page/)

Comment: It's easier to just look at the module's documentation: http://pythonhosted.org/flask-mail/

Comment: My guess is that you are not showing the subject in your template - since you never provide it, you get a validation error.

Comment: Try the cleaned up version and report back if it still gives you an error. You might have simply copy-pasted it wrong.

Comment: @RichardBustos, Could you show your contact.html codes please and what version of Flask you using?

Comment: @RichardBustos The error you have about repeat validation, is not in the code above you showing here. The error will be stopped on your contact page by adding an if statement.

Answer (score 1):

here is an example:

```
<form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
<tr>
    <td>Code name</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='codename' placeholder="name your code" size=20 /></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='name' maxlength=20 size=20 /></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Code</td><br/>
            <td><textarea name='code' rows=4 cols=50></textarea></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type='submit' value='Submit Python Code' /></td>
            </tr>
        </form>
```

edit this to whatever you need. Keep in mind that you will also have to change your flask code to work with this.